# What happens after 14.10 expires? Can I upgrade to 15.10 or do I have to reinstall?

Tags: upgrade, 14.10

I currently have 14.10 installed on my computer. What happens after 14.10 expires? Can I upgrade to 15.10 or do I have to reinstall?

Comment: You are skipping 15.04? :)

Comment: or use the LTS version

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- You can not directly upgrade from 14.10 to 15.10
- If you want to go from 14.10 directly to 15.10 you need to re-install.
- You can upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04, and then from 15.04 to 15.10
- When 14.10 expires, support on Ask Ubuntu ends
- When 14.10 expires, you do not get any more updates. If you can live with that you can keep using 14.10 till the end of the world. It is not advised though. We suggest you upgrade to 15.04.

Comment: Thanks! Will 15.04 be out when 14.10 ends? Do you know if 14.10 gets anymore kernel updates or will it stay at 3.16?

Comment: Maybe I just got one of you wrong, but 15.04 will be released in April. So yes, 15.04 will be released before the end of 14.10. This is the idea with this release cycle. You'll have quiet some time to upgrade before the end, don't worry.

Comment: `Will 15.04 be out when 14.10 ends?` - yes, it will be out a few months before 14.10 support ends.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that, technically, you *can* upgrade straight from 14.10 to 15.10. You may need to edit your software sources (under `/etc/apt`) by hand, and if there are any glitches (which there might be, since it's not an officially supported upgrade path) you'll be mostly on your own, but you *can* do it. I've done crazier things in the past (like, say, "upgrading" from one APT/Debian-based Linux distro to another).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I can also upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to Debian jessie that way. Doesn't mean that is even worth mentioning.

Comment: @muru: Debian uses Linux-libre, your computer may render unable to boot after upgrade.

Comment: @ErkinAlpGüney you do know of non free?

Comment: Non-free is only hosted together, not part of distribution except release freeze policy. Debian Stable has a stricter feature freeze than ours.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the schedule of the Ubuntu releases.

[image]

You may want to read

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases
- http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS

Comment: why always .04 and .10?

Comment: Because that's the month of the release. 16.04 means April 2016. 10.10 means October 2010.

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable to upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04 which is due to be released after 23rd of April and if you check the Software Updater after that date a link to perform the upgrade will show it is available on-line. If your internet access is reasonably fast following the link will perform the upgrade without loosing any of your data. If the link isn't showing after that date check the Software Updater Settings to ensure the update availability is set to any new version.
It should be the same process when the 15.10 version becomes available in October this year.